# How to update the specific value in firebase

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to update the specific value in firebase.
Whenever i click the like button(holder.like) the current value of mlikecount must be fetched from firebase realtime database incremented by 1 and stored back in firebase.
I tried doing but its creating a new node how to do it, please help mme.
This is my onbindViewHolder.

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final FeedAdapter.FeedViewHolder holder, int position) {



    holder.like.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Snackbar.make(v, "Like", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .setAction("Action", null).show();

        }
    });

}
```

Comment: If you want to update a value to the database that is based on the current value of that node, have a look at Firebase's [transactions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write#save_data_as_transactions). If that doesn't allow you to solve the problem, please reproduce the problem with minimal code. See [how to create a minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this this will definitely help you :-

```
DatabaseReference mDatabaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("your table name");
 mDatabaseReference.child("table child").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                int count = Integer.parseInt(snapshot.child("count").getValue().toString);
                //and update your value
                updateYourCount(count+1); //calling a method
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
```

and this is the method to update your count in firebase database:-

```
public static void updateGroupName(int count) {
        DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("your table name").child(" table child name ");
        try {
            HashMap<String, Object> hashMap = new HashMap<>();
            hashMap.put("count", count);
            reference.updateChildren(hashMap);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Comment: it worked for me Thanks

Comment: however my main post value listener creates  a new node at the app